# In parasyte the maxim, what is the name of end song and the name of the conflict song in the middle of the show?

Tags: music, parasyte

I am talking about the song that happens whenever shinichi and migi fight a parasyte. In episode 17, the organ song name at 6:35. Thanks

Comment: Be more specific. If possible (and it should be possible), specify an episode number and timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you happen to be looking for the track called "Full Moon"?

[Click here to listen to it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGy45tGyDCA)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much